# Web2py String var to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, web2py

I have a function:

```
def productdetails():
    if session.login == False:
        redirect(URL('petscart','default','login'))
    myproducts=db(db.Products.product_number > 0).select()
    return dict(products=myproducts)
```

A html file with:

```
<form>
    <input id="product" type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="textAjax({{=product['product_number']}})"/>
</form>
```

And a JS function (textAjax) that takes the product_number passed to it and does some funky stuff, passes some data to a web2py controller.
The strange part is `{{=product['product_number']}}` is passing an integer in this case life is good. if I try to pass a string instead for example `{{=product['product_name']}}` 
The javaScript will show a reference error, `Reference Error "value" cannot be defined.`

I will paste the JS too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function textAjax(id){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/test/default/addtocart',
            data: {
                product:id
            },
            timeout: 1000,
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                jQuery('#output').html(msg)
            },
            error: function(objAJAXRequest, strError){
                $( "#ajaxerror" ).append( " AJAX error:" + strError );
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No one :( as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sting must be wrapped in quotes:

```
textAjax('{{=product['product_number']}}')
```